# Anti CSRF implementation in MVC3

Tags: web-applications, csrf, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have created custom attribute for default AntiForgeryToken validation on each ActionMethod. But when I run my application, I am getting an error message for a few ActionMethods saying:

> A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid.

After some research, I found out that the reason is that we are using SSO (Single Sign On) for authentication and not Forms authentication, as mentioned [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21622043). But I cannot ignore action methods as mentioned in the link since we do not have control over vulnerability scan tool.

Is there any way to implement CSRF even for a SSO enabled applications?

Comment: This sounds like a question about "how to code this up", not a conceptual security question. I've voted to move the question to StackOverflow. Please correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: @Luc - It would be helpful, if u let me know the steps to move this question to Stackoverflow.

Comment: OP, the community is already in the process of migrating this question.

Comment: @Ask_SO If other agree and also vote to move, it will be moved and you'll get a notification that it was moved (just like you get a notification when you get a new comment or answer). If not, the question just remains where it is, and you will get answers here. Either way, you'll just see notifications in your inbox :)